# How should android button and other images be saved

Tags: android, android-layout

I saved button images in android as png. But its not showing right on the phone on photoshop it looks great. What is the best extension to use for images in android? Can .ai be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is technique called "Nine patch image" which makes the buttons to align itself according to screen size.

This link will help you to design buttons for android.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: will this be same for other images also? Except of button? Like other images which are not buttons?

Comment: This will support for all types of images. You can use it even for icons, title images etc.

Answer (score 0):

We normally use png images for buttons or any view's background. Can you please post your xml code where you have used this .png drawable and make sure you have placed .png file in the appropriate drawable.